# python stanford posttager, java command failed after running for some time

Tags: java, python, nltk

I am using stanford posttager toolkit to tag list of words from academic papers. Here is my codes of this part:

```
  st = StanfordPOSTagger(stanford_tagger_path, stanford_jar_path, encoding = 'utf8', java_options = '-mx2048m')
  word_tuples = st.tag(document)
```

document is a list of words derived from nltk.word_tokenize, they come from mormal academic papers so usually there are several thousand of words (mostly 3000 - 4000). I need to process over 10000 files so I keep calling these functions. My program words fine on a small test set with 270 files, but when the number of file gets bigger, the program gives out this error (Java heap space 2G):

```
 raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
 OSError: Java command failed
```

Note that this error does not occur immediately after the execution, it happens after some time of running. I really don't know the reason. Is this because my 3000 - 4000 words are too much ? Thank you very much for help !(Sorry for the bad edition, the error information is too long)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to the code,after I too faced the error.Basically increasing JAVA heapsize solved it.

```
import os
java_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_102\\bin\\java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
path_to_model = "stanford-postagger-2015-12-09/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger"
path_to_jar = "stanford-postagger-2015-12-09/stanford-postagger.jar"
tagger=StanfordPOSTagger(path_to_model, path_to_jar)
tagger.java_options='-mx4096m'          ### Setting higher memory limit for long sentences
sentence = 'This is testing'
print tagger.tag(sentence.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tried increasing the Java stack via the Tagger settings like so

```
stanford.POSTagger([...], java_options="-mxSIZEm")
```

Cf the [docs](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html), default is 1000:

```
def __init__(self, [...], java_options='-mx1000m')
```

In order to test if it is a problem with the size of the dataset, you can tokenize your text into sentences, e.g. using the [Punkt Tokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt) and output them right after tagging.